# HomeControllers not rendering

Tags: java, controllers, spring-tool-suite

I'm using SpringToolSuite with Java and I'm trying to render an index.jsp page onto my localhost:8080, but my Localhost is only going to the Whitelabel error page again & again. I guess it doesn't seem to be recognizing my Homecontroller.java file. The servers are running and have been refreshed. My files are correct. I see no issues anywhere else. What could be wrong that I'm not seeing? How can I render my page?

HomeController.java :

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/your_server")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("")
    public String index(HttpSession session) {
        if (session.isNew()) {
            session.setAttribute("counter", 0);
        } 
        Integer count = (Integer) session.getAttribute("counter");
        count += 1;
        session.setAttribute("counter", count);

        return "index.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/counter")
    public String showCounter(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        if (session.isNew()) {
            session.setAttribute("counter", 0);
        }
        model.addAttribute("counter", session.getAttribute("counter"));
        return "counter.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/reset")
    public String resetCounter(HttpSession session) {
        session.invalidate();
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

CounterApplication.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CounterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CounterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome! Want to count some stuff?</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/counter">How many times has this page been visited?</a>
<p>Oh, hi.</p>
</body>
</html>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <c:out value="${2+2}"/>
```

counter.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>How many times are we going to go through this?!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:out value="${ counter }" />
    <a href="/">Go back.</a>
    <a href="/reset">Reset the counter.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of HomeController to us?

Comment: Sure. I just edited it in.

Comment: In addition to the Home Controller, I also added in the Application file as well as the 2 jsp's that I am trying to render on Localhost8080.